# Using autocomplete feature in C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete

Is there anyway to implement auto complete feature such as shown when typing a few letters in the start->run combo box?

Comment: The short answer would be "Yes". If you tell us more about your scenario and requirements, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx) and [`ComboBox.AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx) properties.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx) but probably it too complex for this task. anyway good control :-)